# Amplify Push Fail - Appsync API error - S3 The specified key does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify, resolver

I am facing an error with cloudformation in which my nested stack got stuck in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED state causing my parent stack to failed. The reason I found out is S3 key missing for my appsync resolvers, although these files are there in S3 deployment bucket.

The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; Request ID: M2X7368PMNF1G; S3 Extended Request ID: WCIc1YLjxOR9KZRxkPb1AGI4xoM6KPofiohiP9ywyps8tSfP6ehHJl8gWk7o=; Proxy: null)

I tired  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-update-rollback-failed/ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-continueupdaterollback.html

to get my parent stack in Update_rollback_complete by skipping the failed resource. This should rollback the parent stack with update complete status and allow for further stack updates but unfortunately not. I drill down the errors and got these error.

Comment: I think the issue s3 key not found is an unclear error message. I found the root cause of why the "push" failed in cloudformation stacks. You need to uncheck the "nested view" and scroll down all events to see what triggered the rollback. I found out mine was started by the misuse of @auth in the model schema. I removed the offending code and the push worked afterward. Weird enough is the codegen works but push won't build.